# How do i validate fields in the other rails table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

Ok so i have a Contact model

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  validates_presence_of :first_name
  validates_presence_of :last_name
  validates_presence_of :email

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :contact
```

And on my form i have fields from that profile and the contact and the validations for the contacts show up but i want to validate the fields from profile. I assumed that adding this to the controller would add to the error messages.

```
    @contact.errors.add(:base, "Profile Company cant be blank")
```

ANy ideas

My form is a form_tag BTW and i cant change that for various reasons..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the validity of associated records when saving the owning record:

```
   class Contact
        validates_associated :profile
```

Comment: but i dont want to validate on every record...just when the profile in the params....is that possible

Comment: You can extend ActiveModel::EachValidator, which passes the current record and you can check if an attribute is set on the record from the form. Something like on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387459/validates-associated-with-models-error-message

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work

```
class Contack < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_associated :profile,
    :if => Proc.new { |a| a.profile.present? }
end
```