# Paperclip - Associated upload validations always lead to "invalid"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, paperclip

```
Rails version: 4.1
Paperclip version: 4.1.1
```

I am using an Upload model to handle my attachments for all other models, since in most cases:

```
model.rb:
has_many :uploads
validates_associated :uploads
```

Currently, there are two validations for my paperclip attachment. Content:

```
# list of file types presented as ... for demonstration only
validates_attachment :attachment, content_type: { content_type:[                         
           "application/pdf",
           "application/vnd.ms-excel","application/excel",
           "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
           "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet",
           "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
           "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation",
           "application/msword", "text/rtf", "text/plain",
           "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", 
           "application/mspowerpoint",
           "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation",
           "application/x-rar-compressed", "application/x-rar", "application/zip"]}
```

and a custom validation which runs a clamdscan (virus check):

```
validate :clean_file

def clean_file
    errors.add :base, "File #{self.attachment.queued_for_write.inspect} is infected!" if
    !self.attachment.queued_for_write.blank? &&
    ("#{system "clamdscan - < \"#{self.attachment.queued_for_write[:original].path}\" | grep FOUND" }")
end
```

Both validations work as expected. The error however always falls to "upload is invalid" or whatever string I provide in my locales file.

`errors.add :base` seems to be ignored.

**Edit:** The error message displayed is from Model, not from Upload.

How can I pass an error message that actually gets displayed????

Thanks

**Edit2:** Added the content validation string

**SOLVED:** Using this approach
[validates associated with model's error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387459/validates-associated-with-models-error-message/7387710#7387710)

Comment: Since you have now solved this, please either post an answer with the solution (giving more detail than just a link) or delete the question.  That way it won't appear as an "open" question with no answers, and can help others in the future if you give your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted above that this is issue is now solved.

This is partially true. The above solution only worked in rendering if the associated object was supplied first in the list.
So instead of using this solution I tried a new one, on view level this time, since errors are produced but not rendered, and it worked well.

Rendering an _errors partial like this ("junk" code is removed):

```
<% if current_object.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
        <% current_object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        <% if current_object.uploads.any? %>
            <% current_object.uploads.each do |u| %>
                <% u.errors.full_messages.each do |umsg| %>
                    <li><%= umsg %></li>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>
```

I get all my errors displayed. At last!