# form_for validation messages for associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a provider model which has comments. I have set the validation for comments to check the presence of the body of the comment presence is true.

here is whats in my model

```
  validates :body, presence: true
```

Here is my form where I am having issues. I get undefined method errors.

```
<%= form_for([@provider, Comment.new] ) do |f| %>
<% if @provider.comments.errors.any? %>
<h2>Errors<h2>
  <ul>
    <% @provider.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
<%= f.text_area :body, cols: 30, rows: 4, class: 'form-control' %>
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id, class: "form-control" %>
<div>
</br>
<%= f.submit :post, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

What is the best way to get the errors for the associated comments model? I have tried a few alternatives but had no luck. If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

errors method needs to be called on a single model like:

```
@comment.errors.any?
```

I would solve the problem like this:

I would set comment in controller's action `@comment = Comment.new`. 
Then use it in `form_for`

```
<%= form_for([@provider, @comment] ) do |f| %>
```

And then you need to check only for comment errors if I got you right:

```
<% if @comment.errors.any? %>
<h2>Errors<h2>
  <ul>
    <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Try it out, I hope it works as you like

Comment: I had an issue when I do <%= form_for([@provider, @comment] ) do |f| %> I get First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty.

Comment: You need to load your provider, usually done with id coming from GET. Something like this in controller: @provider = Provider.find(params[:provider_id])

Comment: I am doing that with a set_provider method but still get the same error. :/

Comment: In my comments controller new action I have @comment  = Comment.new

Comment: I have solved the first argument issue now. But when I submit the form empty it sends me to an error page and not show the message on the page.

Comment: I guess you have some error in create action (or any other that is handling the post). Try some simple debugging there to see if request is received at all. You can paste some more code from that action also

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that your `Provider` validates its comments, [you should use the `validates_associated` method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-associated) in your `Provider` model:

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :comments
  validates_associated :comments
end
```

Unfortunately you can't easily get specific errors from the comments this way. They'll show up in `@provider.errors[:comments]`, but only with the description "Comments is invalid". However, you [could use a custom validator that "bubbles up" errors from associated models](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7387710/3712432).

---

In this case - where you're creating a single new model, and the others aren't being edited - it's easier to create a new `Comment` in your controller and pass that into your view for use in the form. That way you can access `@comment.errors` directly.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get undefined method `errors?' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>