# Rails validates_associated and error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I want to show the validation message from the Child model and it's giving me the basic Child is invalid instead. I tried all solutions out there with no success.
Here, in short, are the models:

```
Class Parent
  ...
  has_many :children, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :parent
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, allow_destroy: true
end

Class Child
  belongs_to :parent
  validate :something
  def something
    check = # Here I check something
    if check < 5
      errors[:base] << "validation on children failed"
    end
  end
end
```

If I add `validates_associated :children` to the Parent model, then I actually get TWO `Children is invalid` messages, which is kinda strange.

Anyway, I can add this block to the Parent model and get whatever validation message I want added to the Parent :base error list:

```
validate do |parent|
  parent.children.each do |child|
    check = # Here I check something
    if check < 5
      errors[:base] << "validation on children failed"
    end
  end
end
```

However, I will still have the validation error message from the Child model on top of this one, so now we would have 3 error messages: "Children is invalidChildren is invalidvalidation on children failed"... ugly.

Since I added the block to the Parent model, I can remove the validation from the Child model, remove the `validates_associated :children` from the Parent, and then saving the instance will not pass the validation, but the data belonging to the Child model will have no validation and will save/update.

Hope this is clearly explained. If you can offer a solution, that would be awesome!

**Update 1: Regarding accepts_nested_attributes_for**

It is very badly documented. As I explained, I get validation on my nsted model without requesting it. I believe the reason is that `accepts_nested_attributes_for` actually runs the validations from the nested model.
This means that the message I get for ALL validations from the nested model, regardless of the type of validation, will give me ONE message. I may manage to adjust the output of that message somehow, but it will remain a single message and not specific to the problem the nested model is experiencing.

Having said that, `accepts_nested_attributes_for` does allow a `reject_if` argument. This doesn't really help me because I need to run a uniqueness validation on the nested model for multiple entries (many children of one parent who all need to have a unique name).

**Summary:**

I believe I need to run the validations in the Child model, but find a way to report back to the Parent model, through accepts_nested_attributes_for, with *specific* messages. That in essence is what I am looking for!
I imagine I will need to write a custom validator. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried this `validates_associated :children , :message=> lambda{|class_obj, obj| obj[:value].errors.full_messages.join(",") }`

Comment: in your child model... why are you adding an error to children? `errors.add(:children` ??? surely you'd just add the error to the attribute that is invalid (or base)?

Comment: @VrushaliPawar - this doesn't work, also, if it did work, it would be limited to a single message and not specific to the cause of the validation failure. See my update above about "accepts_nested_attributes_for"

Comment: @TarynEast - you are right. I updated my question, although this doesn't really change anything fundamental in this question.

Comment: Well it would if that was the thing causing the duplicate error :)

Answer (score 7):

Adding my solution as I hope it's helpful to someone browsing this issue:

```
class Parent < AR
  has_many :children, inverse_of: :parent
  validates_associated :children, message: proc { |_p, meta| children_message(meta) }

  def self.children_message(meta)
    meta[:value][0].errors.full_messages[0]
  end
  private_class_method :children_message
end

class Child < AR
  belongs_to :parent, inverse_of: :children
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Wouldn't have believed it was this complicated...

Comment: Wow, thank you. This is the only place I have seen it mentioned that validates_associated's message param also takes a block! Well done.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveModel Errors class now has copy! and merge! methods for this purpose. Copy replaces the parent messages while merge keeps both: messages from parent and child, using merge or copy will remove the message from parent

you write it in **parent model** as follow and use forms_errors_for:

```rb
  validate do |parent|
    errors.messages.clear 
    parent.children.each do |children|
      next if children.valid?
      
      errors.merge! children.errors
    end
  end
```

definition from ActiveModel errors

```rb
 # Merges the errors from <tt>other</tt>.
    #
    # other - The ActiveModel::Errors instance.
    #
    # Examples
    #
    #   person.errors.merge!(other)

    def merge!(other)
      @messages.merge!(other.messages) { |_, ary1, ary2| ary1 + ary2 }
      @details.merge!(other.details) { |_, ary1, ary2| ary1 + ary2 }
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Proposed solution**

Such a simple thing should not be so annoying to fix. I still haven't found any elegant solution but I don't have more time to waste on this.
In fairness to others, I will post my (ugly) solution. Note, this solution still needs work.

I ended up creating a method to collect the errors from the two models instead of letting Rails do it.

```
def collect_errors
  errors = []
  if self.errors.any?
    parent_errors = self.errors.full_messages
    parent_errors.delete("YOURCHILDMODELNAME is invalid")
    errors << parent_errors.join(", ")
  end
  self.children.each do |child|
    if child.errors.any?
       errors << child.errors.messages.values.join(", ")
    end
  end
   return errors.join(", ")
end
```

I then do all the validation on each model and in the view I simply display the collected errors and not the parent model errors:

```
flash[:warning] = "Failed to create Parent: #{@parent.collect_errors}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also can combine error messages:

```
@parent_model.children.each do |child_record|
  child_record.errors.messages.each do |field, messages|
    messages.each do |msg|
      @parent_model.errors.add("#{child_record.id} #{field}", msg)
    end
  end
end
```